# SQL: Group by count(*) as pct of total table row count

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've spent a lot of time searching for this, please let me know if duplicate.

I need to write a grouped query that returns the categories of records with the count of each type of category. Something like this:

```
select categorynum, count(*) from tbl group by categorynum;
```

So far so good. Now what I need is to determine what % of the total each category's count occupies. The best I have come up with is this, which I do not like, it feels dirty:

```
select categorynum, count(*), count(*)/(select count(*) from tbl) from tbl group by categorynum;
```

It works, but it's really nagging me to do it this way. The database I use is Postgres syntax compatible, and `count(*)` on a table is really fast, so there is no huge speed hit for doing a `count(*)` on the table, though I would like to write better SQL if at all possible.

So is there a better way to write this? This is a situation I run into often, so I would like to write my queries correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since PostgreSQL supports window functions, you could do something like this:

```
select categorynum,count,100*count/(sum(count) over ())::numeric as count_pct
from(
    select categorynum,count(1)
    from tbl
    group by categorynum
)a;
```

Comment: This is more complicated than the original, but would it run faster? This type of query has a lot of potential applications, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Well, if there are few values of `categorynum` relative to the number of rows in `tbl`, then most of the work will be done in the subquery.  If the proportion of distinct `categorynums` relative to the number of rows in `tbl` is relatively high, then the `sum` may slow you down too much.  I'd check the query plan via an `explain` for both queries.  And you're very welcome.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the count(*) on the table as a separate query and then join that with your original query in the FROM portion of your SELECT statement.  That should be quicker than putting it in the SELECT part.

```
select categorynum, categorycount, total
from (select categorynum, count(*) as categorycount
      from tbl
      group by categorynum) categories,
     (select count(*) as total from tbl) totals
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the only option I had before... The thing is this table is always getting data added to it, and also I would much rather have a single query than have to run two queries and then type the numbers into a calculator/spreadsheet to get the percentages.

Comment: I think the answerer had a single query in mind... I will write a suggestion into the answer where it will be readable.

Comment: although the example I just added isn't any more efficient than your example in the question, they both result in two full scans of the table. ah well, these things are only really learned by trying them.

Comment: Yes, in Postgres maybe they do full table scans, but I stated in my question that `count(*)` in my DB (which is Postgres syntax compatible) it does not cause a full table scan, so that is not a factor here.